# How to add Array of Fields to ProjectionOperation with Spring data mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, aggregation, spring-mongo

I have this parto of query in mongo that return an array of fields.

```
{ $project:
    {
        ...
        result:
            [
                { sumShotsOfOneAttempted: '$sumShotsOfOneAttempted1', sumShotsOfOneFailed: '$sumShotsOfOneFailed1'},
                { sumShotsOfOneAttempted: '$sumShotsOfOneAttempted2', sumShotsOfOneFailed: '$sumShotsOfOneFailed2'}
            ]

    }
}
```

I'm trying to build the same with spring-mongodb using ProjectionOperation:

```
ProjectionOperation projectStage = Aggregation.project("fieldId");
```

And I want to add the fields inside of array to this projectStage, but I only know how to add one by one as `projectStage.and("sumShotsOfOneAttempted1").as(sumShotsOfOneAttempted);` but not arrays.

My depndendencies of spring.mongodb:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in you other post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54709869/how-build-mongo-aggregation-operations-of-spring-data-mongo-with-bucle-for-add-f)

```
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project("matches");

for(String typeOfShots : typesOfShots) {
    projectionOperation = projectionOperation.and("sum"+typeOfShots+"Attempted").as("sum"+typeOfShots+"Attempted");
}
```